# AutoFixture Customization on single object creation

Tags: c#, autofixture

So, I have a object with a lot of IEnumerable properties.
In a unit test i want to do something like this:

```
var subsequentAgreement = _fixture.Build<Foo>()
                                          .With(dto => dto.Bars,
                                              _fixture.CreateMany<Bar>())
                                          .Create();
```

And for the other `IEnumerable<T>` properties i want a `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`

I have a `ISpecimenBuilder`

```
public class EmptyEnumerableBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        object returnObject = new NoSpecimen(request);
        var type = request as Type;
        if (type != null && type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var typeArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
            if(!typeArguments.Any() || typeof(IEnumerable<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                returnObject = Array.CreateInstance(typeArguments.Single(), 0);
        }

        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

which i add like so: `_fixture.Customizations.Add(new EmptyEnumerableBuilder());`
And that works just fine, except all of the other objects i create now have Empty enumerables.

I am looking for a way to apply this `EmptyEnumerableBuilder` for a single `_fixture.Build<>()` and leave the rest default, but i can't seem to find a way.

I have tried using a type limitation like so:

```
_fixture.Customize<SubsequentAgreementLimitationsDto>(composer => new EmptyEnumerableBuilder());
```

But strangely all other objects created by fixture still have empty enumerables

Comment: What's wrong with the first code block?

Comment: Nothing, that is how i want it to be, but normal auto fixture behavior would generate the standard list of 3 items per IEnumerable<T> property. and i would like to change that default to Enumerable.Empty<T>(). for that _fixture.Build or when building an object of type Foo.

Comment: Ah, I see. [Consider making your collection properties read-only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389.aspx), then that will not happen.

Comment: So, there is no "clean" way to change the behavior of Auto Fixture "temporarily"? As IEnumerable<T> doesn't support .Add so Read only isn't a real option

Comment: Well, you can use [OmitAutoProperties](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/07/23/DisablingAutoPropertiesInAutoFixture), but that's going to disable population of all properties, and not only collection properties.

Comment: That will have to do then, Thanx!

Comment: That said, your `EmptyEnumerableBuilder` isn't that far off the mark. Instead of looking for a `Type`, look for a `request` that's a `PropertyInfo`. That should give you the fine-grained filtering ability that it seems like you're requesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something convention-driven, you may be able to use [Albedo](https://github.com/AlbedoOrg/Albedo) to empty all writable `IEnumerable<>` properties. You could start with something like this:

```
public class EmtpyEnumerables : ReflectionVisitor<object>
{
    private object value;

    public EmtpyEnumerables(object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override object Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }

    public override IReflectionVisitor<object> Visit(PropertyInfoElement propertyInfoElement)
    {
        var pi = propertyInfoElement.PropertyInfo;
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsConstructedGenericType && 
            pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) &&
            pi.CanWrite)
        {
            var elementType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            pi.SetValue(value, Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 0));
            return this;
        }

        return base.Visit(propertyInfoElement);
    }
}
```

Assuming that `Foo` looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Baz> Bazs { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Qux> Quxs { get; set; }

    public string Corge { get; set; }

    public int Grault { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void FillBarsZeroOutAllOtherSequences()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var actual = fixture.Create<Foo>();
    new TypeElement(actual.GetType()).Accept(new EmtpyEnumerables(actual));
    actual.Bars = fixture.CreateMany<Bar>();

    Assert.NotEmpty(actual.Bars);
    Assert.Empty(actual.Bazs);
    Assert.Empty(actual.Quxs);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual.Corge);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(int), actual.Grault);
}
```

If you think it's too much bother to write out `new TypeElement(actual.GetType()).Accept(new EmtpyEnumerables(actual));`, I'm sure you can figure out to hide it in a helper method.

Comment: Wow thanks for you answer, as one of you many dedicated followers I would love the mark this as answered, but although this would work, it would require other dependencies, thus not really answering the question. So don't really know conduct in this case :-$

Comment: @LordSauron If this doesn't answer your question, then you don't have to mark it as the answer. That's perfectly fine. This is just the best I could come up with...